# Advice needed on Google Scripts-Send email per row of data (Beginner)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am hoping this is fairly straightforward. I'm very, very new to scripts and just need advice on what I need to be doing. Essentially, I have this :

```
function myFunction() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let address = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  let subject = msg '${B2}-Upcoming Due Date for invoice ${C2}'
  let body = msg 'Dear Sir/Madam. I hope you are well. This email serves as a reminder that your invoice ${C2} will be due on {D2}. Please advise as as to any issues that may cause delay in payment or if you require any additional information from us. In the case that we do not have the correct details for queries relating to invoicing and payments we ask that you make us aware and we will update our system.'
  MailApp.sendEmail(address, subject, body)
 
  
}
```

How far off am I, and will this expand to read all rows? (It will need to send an email per row.)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you share what your Google Sheet looks like as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Remove `msg` from the `subject` and `body`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let [A2,B2,C2,D2] = sheet.getRange("A2:D2").getValues()[0];
  let address = A2;
  let subject = `${B2}-Upcoming Due Date for invoice ${C2}`
  let body = `Dear Sir/Madam. I hope you are well.This email serves as a reminder that your invoice ${C2} will be due on ${D2}. Please advise as as to any issues that may cause delay in payment or if you require any additional information from us. In the case that we do not have the correct details for queries relating to invoicing and payments we ask that you make us aware and we will update our system.`
  MailApp.sendEmail(address, subject, body)
}
```

Problems Detected:

- Using single quotes where backticks were required
- Undefined variables B2,C2,D2
- Missing $ in ${}

References:

- [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: This worked great, the only issue i have now is how to apply this to every row, and for some reason and some slight formatting stuff, mainly that it is pulling my date as Nov 04 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time). rather than just 04/11/23 like it is in the cell